# How can I quickly remove tea stain from clothes

Tags: cleaning, clothing

Most of the times it happens to me that whenever I am in hurry tea fall on my clothes and I could not find other way instead of washing but it do not not remove this.Is there any thing that can quickly remove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a liquid detergent and rub gently into the tea stain. Allow the detergent to stand on the tea stain for at least 5 minutes. 
Apply a thick layer of baking soda directly to the stain while the tea is still wet. 
If these tricks not work then apply a stain remover stick, gel, or spray and let stand for 5 minutes before washing normally.